# Sudo apt-get update gives an error

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I get the following error when doing `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Try this `sudo sh -c 'rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*; apt-get update'`; Let me know if helps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your sources file is corrupted. Remove the corrupted source file by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal, and type in

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in `sudo software-properties-gtk`. This will open software-properties-gtk and a new `sources.list` will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)